# Bundle Config is Missing in facebook instant game

Tags: html

Bundle Config is Missing
You must include a bundle config in your upload
i'm facing this problem during upload facebook instant game kindly help me
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You must have a fbapp-config.json file in your root directory. You can see the properties [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/onboarding/instant-games/get-started/bundle-config)
example:

```
       {
         "instant_games": {
           "orientation": "LANDSCAPE",
           "navigation_menu_version": "NAV_BAR",
           "match_player_config": { "min_context_size": 2, "max_context_size": 5 }
         }
       }
```